# didReceiveRemoteNotification not called on background (Firebase, Postman, iOS)

Tags: ios, notifications, background, push, silent

### Problem: `didReceiveRemoteNotification` is not called.

I do get notifications when my app is in background. (real device).

I just want to have `didReceiveRemoteNotification` called whenever notification arrives in background and no user interaction has been made (no tapping). 
(My device is iOS 16.3 and Xcode is 14.1)

### What I did

I have a **Firebase** server and I sent a push notification from **Postman**.

##### My header

[image]
I added apns-push-type, apns-priority, apns-topic ([Apple Background push doc](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/setting_up_a_remote_notification_server/pushing_background_updates_to_your_app#:%7E:text=Additionally%2C%20the%20notification%E2%80%99s%20POST%20request%20should%20contain%20the%20apns%2Dpush%2Dtype%20header%20field%20with%20a%20value%20of%20background%2C%20and%20the%20apns%2Dpriority%20field%20with%20a%20value%20of%205.))

##### My Body

- I also tried true and "true" for `content-available`.

```
{
    "aps" : {
      "content-available" : 1
      },
    "to":"my fcm token",
    "notification" : {
        "title" : "Alarm",
        "body" : "Testing"
        }
}
```

##### Other settings

I did `FirebaseApp.configure()`,
`Messaging.messaging().delegate = self`,
`UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()`, `Messaging.messaging().apnsToken = deviceToken`. 
I also added `Push Notifications` and `Background Modes` (Remote notifications, Background fetch)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using the

```
application(_:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:)
```

Did you try changing the content-available to true or "true" instead of using 1?
Refer:[didReceiveRemoteNotification not called Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31279979/didreceiveremotenotification-not-called-swift?rq=1)

Comment: Thanks for the comment!
I just realized that this method is called sometimes. And it worked when `content-available` was true, "true" or 1. It just doesn't work all the times. If I launch the app 20 times, it's gonna work once for the first notification.

Comment: I figured out that it is called when I the notification is received right before `didEnterBackgroundNotification` is called. Meaning still not called after entering background 

Comment: Did you try the push notification test from firebase something on the lines of https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/first-message
I might be working on something around this next and I can investigate a bit more when I do to test.

Comment: @joey did you solve it? how did you solve  it? i have the exact error.